# Why is this house bitchin?

Tags: analysis, dialogue, arrowverse, the-flash

In *The Flash* S04E01, Barry started talking in cryptic language but on thing he said looks quite weird was:

> This house is bitchin

Which everyone noticed is not how Barry talks, but this is repeated many times later in the show by other characters and becomes like a recurring joke.

But what was the significance of it being even there? Is it some reference to something else or just a reference to a later episode when the house was going haywire?

Comment: Too bad he didn't say that about the kitchen!   It totally would have rhymed  :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It *is* a reference to something else. As of the time the question was asked, this has not been revealed to the audience on the show. The gibberish Barry was speaking and writing when he first emerged from the Speed Force wasn't actually gibberish. Many of the details of things he said/drew have come up later, and according to [Grant Gustin](http://comicbook.com/dc/2017/12/25/the-flash-is-this-house-still-bitchin/), everything Barry said was significant.

The ultimate meaning of that message will likely be part of the climax of the season, and probably relates to something that happened to Barry while he was in the Speed Force.

Comment: This gets referenced in dialogue every few episodes, so it’s likely significant.

Answer (score 0):

Its a clue to something that will come in the future, and most likely, on the finale of the season. I think they are trying to create a "it was right there in front of us moment" when the meaning behind that phrase is revealed and starts to make sense as the events of the show progress. 
That is why the phrase has been repeated multiple times across several episodes.